# How to automatically create variables which are column extracts from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, octave

I have an `n*n` matrix and I want to extract every 3 columns and keep the result in different variables.

I know that it is possible to do it in this way:

```
A1 = A(:,1:3); 
A2 = A(:,4:6); 
A3 = A(:,7:9);
```

But I would like to simplify and automate this for managing a large amount of data!

```
A =

[1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18
 3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27
 4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36
 5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45
 6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54
 7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63
 8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72
 9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81]
```

Expected result:

```
A1 =               
[1  2   3          
 2  4   6          
 3  6   9          
 4  8   12
 5  10  15
 6  12  18
 7  14  21
 8  16  24
 9  18  27]

A2 =
[4  5   7 
 8  10  12
 12 15  18
 16 20  24 
 20 25  30
 24 30  36
 28 35  42 
 32 40  48
 36 45  54]

A3 =
[7  8   9 
 14 16  18
 21 24  27
 28 32  36 
 35 40  45
 42 48  54
 49 56  63  
 56 64  72 
 63 72  81]
```

Comment: Putting subsets of an existing matrix into different variables is a very inefficient way to do things and will lead to longer and more confusing code.  Why do you not want to use the `A(:, 1:3)` syntax (or even with a variable, `A(:, c:c+2)`)? What do you intend to do with these variables after you've created them all?

Comment: I'm assuming A2 should start 4 5 6...?

Answer (score 6):

You really shouldn't split A this way. If you really want to adress A in 3 column block then use something like

```
A = (1:9).*((1:9).');
%% create anonymous function which can be called as Ac(1), Ac(2) and so on
Ac = @(n) A(:,(n-1)*3+1:n*3)

octave:2> Ac(1)
ans =

    1    2    3
    2    4    6
    3    6    9
    4    8   12
    5   10   15
    6   12   18
    7   14   21
    8   16   24
    9   18   27

octave:3> Ac(2)
ans =

    4    5    6
    8   10   12
   12   15   18
   16   20   24
   20   25   30
   24   30   36
   28   35   42
   32   40   48
   36   45   54
```

Comment: This is the best one so far, but it should be noted that this does not allow assignment to the variable `A` or `Ac()` and does not reflect changes made to `A` after the anonymous function is created.

Comment: I've suggested a solution to the second of these issues in my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
C = mat2cell(A,size(A,1),ones(size(A,2)/3,1)*3);
```

It will split your matrix into subcells.

You can access the information contained by those cells with:

```
C{1}
C{2}  %and so on
```

Answer (score 4):

### Summary

You have a few options

- Using `eval`. Don't do this, it's bad practise. However, it does directly answer your question in case you were curious *how* to do it. Because you shouldn't use this, I've included it last!
- Using cell arrays or matrices. This is how I would do it, although if your data set is very large you may get memory issues. It does make indexing very simple, and allows you to over-write sections of the array.
- Using an anonymous function as shorthand for your indexing. This is a read-only way to quickly access your data, and has no memory footprint.

---

### Using cell arrays and 3D matrices

As suggested by Mathworks in the above linked blog, you could store the partitions in a cell array...

```
myCellArray = cell(size(A,2)/3,1)
for n = 1:3:size(A,2)
    myCellArray{1+(n-1)/3} = A(:,n:n+2)
end
% For accessing:
myCellArray{1} % = A1
```

or use a 3D matrix

```
% option 1
my3DArray = reshape(A,9,3,[]);
% option 2 (same structure as above cell example)
my3DArray = zeros(size(A,1), 3, size(A,2)/3);
for n = 1:3:size(A,2)
    my3DArray(:,:,1+(n-1)/3) = A(:,n:n+2);
end
% For accessing:
my3DArray(:,:,1); % = A1
```

The best option is not to duplicate `A` in memory and just index it as needed, either directly or using a helper function as shown above.

---

### Using an anonymous function

You can create a function which just essentially lets you write in short hand if this is a common indexing operation. Inline functions written with the `@()` notation are called anonymous functions.

```
% Create A
A = repmat(1:9, 9, 1);
% Create helper function
An = @(n) A(:,(n-1)*3+1:n*3);
% For accessing:
An(1); % An(1) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; ...]
```

However, you **cannot** assign using this.

```
An(1) = [11 12 13; 11 12 13; ...] % wont work
```

And you may be surprised if you change `A` then try and use it.

```
% Change A
A = repmat(11:19, 9, 1); % A = [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19; 11 12 ...]
% indexing
An(1); % An(1) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; ...] not the new values!!
```

To get around this second point, we could also pass `A` into the helper function:

```
An = @(M,n) M(:,(n-1)*3+1:n*3);
A = repmat(1:9, 9, 1);
An(A,1); % An(1) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; ...];
A = repmat(11:19, 9, 1);
An(A,1); % An(1) = [11 12 13; 11 12 13; ...]; as desired!
```

---

### Using `eval`

You can easily assign the variables like so

```
% Create some 9x9 matrix A
A = repmat(1:9, 9, 1);
% Loop through A, create A1, A2, ...
for n = 1:3:size(A,2)
    eval(['A', num2str(1+(n-1)/3), ' = A(:,n:n+2)']);
end
% Gives the result
% A1 = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; ...], A2 = [4 5 6; 4 5 6; ...], ...
```

#### This is very bad practise in MATLAB

**Please read this post by Mathworks on [avoiding eval](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)**. There is no reason why setting up variables in this way is better than *any* other method.

- You won't know how many variables you're making
- You won't know all the variable names you've generated
- You've duplicated your "big amount of data" in memory
- `eval` is harder to debug when things (inevitably) go wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Don't create dynamic variables. If really needed, [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `A` into a 3D array as follows:

```
A = reshape(A,size(A,1),3,[]); 
%where 3 is the number of columns you want to extract at a time
```